# Does reduced casting cost affect casting of cards with variable casting cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I know the title's wording is a bit confusing, so here's an example scenario:
I have [Etherium Sculptor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Etherium+Sculptor) in play and I cast [Chimeric Mass](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=209714) for 0 mana. My understanding ([this post](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/21128/how-do-i-handle-casting-a-spell-with-a-cost-of-x-when-the-casting-cost-is-reduce) and my understanding of the rules) is that Chimeric Mass will have one charge counter on it as opposed to zero. Is this correct?

Comment: @diego It's not quite a duplicate, though I know they are similar. In my question I'm also concerned about how many charge counters are on Chimeric Mass if I technically paid 0 mana for it.

Comment: What part of your question is not answered by the answer to that question?

Comment: @player3 The mass doesn't care how much mana you paid, it cares what X is

Comment: I suppose it may be answered by that question, but if so it wasn't clear to me. Seeing as I didn't technically pay any mana for Chimeric Mass, does it still get a charge counter for the one mana covered by Etherium Sculptor?

Comment: Did you even read the answer to the question you linked? It tells you exactly how X spells work with cost reduction and what the resulting value of X is.

Comment: I did, but like I said it wasn't especially clear to me. But diego just confirmed my understanding, and I realize that what he said is essentially the same as the answer in the linked post.

Comment: Unless you somehow thing it matters that you're talking about an Artifact instead of a Sorcery -- it doesn't -- this is the exact same question as the one to which you linked. You don't calculate X based on how much you payed. You pay based on what value you chose for X.

Comment: @player3 for future reference, if you have a question which is marked as a duplicate but you really don't think it is, the best way to handle that is to edit your question to make it explicitly clear what it is that you're asking which is not covered by the other question. Once you edit it, it goes into a queue to be reviewed for reopening. But it sounds like you got your answer in this case, which is good. Welcome to B&CG Stack Exchange!